# Yocto - iwlib.h no such file or directory

Tags: linux, libraries, yocto

I am doing a project that needs iwlib. On my PC it works fine but I cannot add my project to Yocto. I get error `<iwlib.h> No such file or directory.` I have tried to add `iw` to the image and to `DEPENDS` variable in my project recipe file but it seems doesn't work. I get still the same error. I used to thought that the `iw` files were installed in another path that on my PC, so I have built the image with `iw` but without my app and next I have used `find -iname` to find this file in all my Yocto repositiry but I didn't find it.

Do you have any idea how to add iw package to Yocto? Thank you in advanced for any help.

**EDIT:** The error:

```
 In file included MyClass.cpp:1:
 MyClass.hpp:5:10: fatal error: iwlib.h: No such file or directory
     5 | #include <iwlib.h>
       |          ^~~~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
```

The error occurs during compilation process. The file really doesn't appear in my Yocto repository. I thought that the file `iwlib.h` is a part of `iw` packege. In `.manifest` file I can see the package `iw` but I still don't have `iwlib.h` file.

Comment: The error seems to be in the source code or the configuration of the build. Kindly share a more detailed error log for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iwlib.h` is not part of `iw` software but `wireless-tools`, c.f. https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwlib.h and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git/tree/ (no iwlib.h).

`wireless-tools` was removed from openembedded-core because it is SO outdated and unmaintained that it didn't make sense anymore (especially since `iw` superseded `wireless-tools`. The last recipe was in sumo and its content back then is available here: https://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wireless-tools?id=95957e3a5fc72406391441627fb19bc36c655072

See https://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/recipes-connectivity?id=f1978b7e1d68bd7813ae048ff9a37716618a473c to know why it was removed.

I guess it'd make sense for you to migrate to `iw` and use I'd assume `iw.h` instead? Otherwise, you'll need to take the old `wireless-tools` recipe, eventually adapt it to your release of Yocto and then add it to the `DEPENDS` of your software.